# Implement OnItemLongClickLister in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

i am working on one project in which i have used open source code, but at one point i am stuck, in this code i am using RecyclerView in which onRecycleItemClickListener is already implemented but now i need to implement onItemLongClickListener in existing code

```
public abstract class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter<T, VH extends BaseClickListenerViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

private List<T> objectsList;
protected final BaseActivity baseActivity;
protected final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
protected final Resources resources;
protected QBUser currentQbUser;

// Package private because we need access in BaseViewHolder but not in child classes
OnRecycleItemClickListener<T> onRecycleItemClickListener;
AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClickListener;

public BaseRecyclerViewAdapter(BaseActivity baseActivity) {
    this.baseActivity = baseActivity;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(baseActivity);
    resources = baseActivity.getResources();
    objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public BaseRecyclerViewAdapter(BaseActivity baseActivity, List<T> objectsList) {
    this(baseActivity);
    this.objectsList = objectsList;
    currentQbUser = AppSession.getSession().getUser();
}

public void setList(List<T> items) {
    objectsList = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItem(T item) {
    objectsList.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(objectsList.size() - 1);
}

public void addItem(int position, T item) {
    objectsList.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void addAll(Collection<T> collection) {
    objectsList.addAll(collection);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(objectsList.size() - collection.size(), collection.size());
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    objectsList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void removeItem(T item) {
    int position = objectsList.indexOf(item);
    if (position != -1) {
        objectsList.remove(item);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public void clear() {
    objectsList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objectsList.size();
}

public T getItem(int position) {
    return objectsList.get(position);
}

public List<T> getAllItems() {
    return objectsList;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return objectsList.size() == 0;
}

public void setOnRecycleItemClickListener(OnRecycleItemClickListener<T> onRecycleItemClickListener) {
    this.onRecycleItemClickListener = onRecycleItemClickListener;
}

protected void displayAvatarImage(String uri, ImageView imageView) {
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, imageView, ImageLoaderUtils.UIL_USER_AVATAR_DISPLAY_OPTIONS);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this class [`ItemTouchListenerAdapter`](https://github.com/ismoli/DynamicRecyclerView/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/du/android/recyclerview/ItemTouchListenerAdapter.java) in your code to easily add support for both item clicks and long-clicks.

Usage:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemTouchListenerAdapter(recyclerView, this));
```

Code:

```
public class ItemTouchListenerAdapter extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    public interface RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(RecyclerView parent, View clickedView, int position);

        void onItemLongClick(RecyclerView parent, View clickedView, int position);
    }

    private RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener listener;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public ItemTouchListenerAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener listener) {
        if (recyclerView == null || listener == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("RecyclerView and Listener arguments can not be null");
        }
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(recyclerView.getContext(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = getChildViewUnder(e);
        if (view != null) {
            view.setPressed(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = getChildViewUnder(e);
        if (view == null) return false;

        view.setPressed(false);
        int position = recyclerView.getChildPosition(view);
        listener.onItemClick(recyclerView, view, position);
        return true;
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        View view = getChildViewUnder(e);
        if (view == null) return;
        int position = recyclerView.getChildPosition(view);
        listener.onItemLongClick(recyclerView, view, position);
        view.setPressed(false);
    }

    @Nullable
    private View getChildViewUnder(MotionEvent e) {
        return recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: add a new class named `ItemTouchListenerAdapter` to your project and copy this code into it. then use it using `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemTouchListenerAdapter(recyclerView, this));` in your Activity/Fragment containing your `RecyclerView`

Comment: getting error ItemTouchListenerAdapter cannot be applied to (RecyclerView, Activity)

Comment: check the constructor, it accepts classes that implement the interface `RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener`, you need your activity to implement this interface